# Combining two arrays in c, function causing error

Tags: c, arrays, function, for-loop, structure

As a part of a bigger program, I'm trying to combine two arrays of structures.  I also was trying to pass the new one into a printing function.  I know the function works, because when I pass one of the arrays into it, it prints correctly.

This is the structure, I'm sure it's correct because when I pass an array of it into another function the function works.

```
typedef struct {
        long unsigned bibnum; 
        char lastname[charnum];
        char firstname[charnum];
        int grade;
        char team[charnum];
        char state[charnum];
        int time1;
        float time2;
    } runner_t;
```

My first two arrays are runarrayboys and runarraygirls, and are arrays of structure type runner_t.  The third one is runarrayall.  This is how I tried to combine it.  When I try to run it I get a segmentation fault.  After putting printfs all over the place I'm pretty sure it's in the declaration line of the second for loop.

```
    while (p<(x+y))
        {
            for (q=0; q<x; q++)
                {
                    runarrayall[q] = runarrayboys[q];
                    p++;
                    /* printingfucntion(runarrayall[q]);  */
                }
            for (q=x; q<(x+y); q++) 
                {
                    printf("in for loop2 \n");
                    runarrayall[q] = runarraygirls[n];
                    n++;
                    p++;
                }
        }
```

When I uncomment the printingfunction, I get this error:

```
LA2.c:(.text+0xdaa): undefined reference to `printingfucntion'
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
```

Even though I passed in the array the same way I did with the others which work

Comment: I assume that the typo "printingfucntion" isn't an accident?

Comment: Wow, I make the most stupid mistakes.  Thank you!  So I fixed that and that part prints, I still get a segmentation fault in the second for loop though

Comment: How are you allocating the arrays? Did you malloc them with their number of elements times sizeof(runner_t)?

Comment: @Sean I used malloc, and like this: 
     runarrayboys = (runner_t *)malloc(x * sizeof(runner_t));   
     runarraygirls = (runner_t *)malloc(y * sizeof(runner_t));

Comment: What about runarrayall? Also is n initialized to 0?

Comment: @Sean thank you so much, I really really appreciate it.  I forgot to define runarrayall using malloc which was the issue.  I changed it and it works now!

Answer (score 2):

are you initializing runarrayall?

```
runarrayall = (runner_t *)malloc( sizeof(runner_t)*(x + y) );
```

Comment: This is more a comment than an answer, but +1 since you seem to have guessed correctly